# Product page not found if product data is set Appointment Service

Tags: customization, woocommerce-offtopic, page-template

I installed the booked plugin and integrated with Woocemmerce.  When I checked the product type to be appointments service, why was my product page not found on frontend.  where is the code i need to fix?  if you provide a solution, it is worth it
[image]

Comment: The page URL might just have changed, e.g. because it's no longer the same post type after the edit. I don't know these plugins: isn't there a 'preview' or 'go to page' link on this edit page that you can use to find the working URL?

Comment: But if this is a problem with the Booked plugin you might get better answers by asking them directly.